# How to use dependency in multiple dropdown?

Tags: magento-1.9, dependency

my code:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("tuition_form", array("legend"=>Mage::helper("tuition")->__("Student information")));

    $fieldset->addField("secondary", "multiselect", array(              
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name"=>  "subject[secondary]",
        'values'   => Example_Tuition_Block_Adminhtml_Student_Grid::getValueArray34(),
    ));
     $fieldset->addField("others", "text", array(                   
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name"=>  "subject[others]",

    ));
    $this->setForm($form);
     $this->setChild('form_after',

        // The content of the "form_after" block is a Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Element_Dependence block typ
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap('junior', 'junior')
            ->addFieldMap('others', 'others')

       ->addFieldDependence('others', 'junior', 'chinese')
       );
   return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

my multiple dropdown

[image]

here if i m select chinese i want text field. if i m select chinese,malay,...etc than i m getting textbox but when i m also select physics or science that time i m not getting textbox how to solve this problem?

Comment: So, you are trying to have a multi select dropdown? and the selected values should be shown in the above text box?

Comment: Nooo, i have multi select dropdown if i m select chinese i want to display textbox. not shown in textbox,its empty textbox it should be display in form if i select chinese otherwise it should be hide

Comment: Write a click event on those list item elements. Whenever user clicks on a list item, the click event gets triggered, in that triggered function you can display a textbox based on the text inside that clicked list item.

Comment: it is in admin side not in frontend

Comment: Still you can do that. Keep this in mind whether it is frontend or backend both runs on the client code which is javascript. :) (_you can add javascript code through phtml files also_)

Comment: please provide where you have added above code? location of a form code.

Comment: please provide code for your form.php and edit.php files if you have to add functionality in admin section.

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks for give me right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here using **javascript** i can show or hide textbox not using dependency:

```
$field = $fieldset->addField("junior", "multiselect", array(
    "class" => "required-entry",
    "required" => true,
    "name" => "subject[junior]",
    'onchange' => 'change(this.value)',
    'values' => Example_Tuition_Block_Adminhtml_Student_Grid::getValueArray35(),
));
$field->setAfterElementHtml("<script>

        function change(selectItem){

            var e = document.getElementById('junior');
            var arr = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length; i++) {
                    if(e.options[i].selected){
                        var val = e.options[i].value;
                        arr.push(val);
                    }
                }
            console.log(arr);
            var values = arr.indexOf('chinese');
            if (values != -1) { 
                document.getElementById('others').style.display = '';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'none';   
            } 
        }
        </script>");

$other = $fieldset->addField("others", "text", array(
    "class" => "required-entry",
    "required" => true,
    "name" => "subject[others]",

));
$other->setAfterElementHtml("<script>
                document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'none';               
            </script>");
```

Using this I can show and hide textbox on change of multiple dropdown.